# LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_BLOCK

Tags: magento

I can't keep myself logged in to the admin panel.
[image]

I can login in admin panel, but after click in any thongs link of menu, this action redirect me to logoff of the admin panel.

This logs var/log/debug

```
LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_BLOCK

[2020-06-17 18:13:56] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://local.com.br/adminadmin/admin/index/index/key/0097129e6ac9734d9df46986f7e4229af69b1fa4fda4fe22fdb4d810c4a45b6c/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["BACKEND_MAINMENU"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"}} []
[2020-06-17 18:13:56] main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at /var/www/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Request/BackendValidator.php:176)"} []
[2020-06-17 18:13:57] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://local/adminadmin/admin/dashboard/index/key/ff3cb02e431b818aeb20d66951f6996550eca2fd529e1b408c603949be756da0/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"LOCKED_RECORD_INFO_BLOCK_c2d0e379ddf3cdab54f7ae12e1857228ed047058"}} []
[2020-06-17 18:13:58] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/pt_BR/tinymce.js' [] []
[2020-06-17 18:13:58] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/pt_BR/tinymce.js' [] []
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve this?